# Drawing rectangular nodes in graph + python

Tags: python

I am trying to visualise a btree in python and would like help for it.

I have a node list of elements and I want it to be displayed in a rectangular node of its exact size.

I know that one method is simply create a node and have its label as a complete list but I am want it look more nice that is create a rectangular nodes box like with each element of list in one box

Is there any way to do so ... You can tell any library that I can use...I have no constraint in use of them.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), a graph visualization tool that's been around for a long time.

Here's a Python binding:  http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz/

Comment: Sorry about that.  If you're Windows-only, you should probably tag that on your original question.